# How to make an IconPicker, a Widget to list icons for the user to pick

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'd like to use an IconPicker where the user can search for an Icon and select it.
If I search for "arrow" it would give me: arrow_upward, arrow_back, arrow_back_ios and so on.
Can you link me a library that can do this? or give an idea of how I can accomplish that?

I've looked everywhere, the only one I could find it was this: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_picker.
But it doesn't have the search option.

Comment: Try to use a map with keys as Icon name, values as Icon Widget. For searching: use a TextFormField with a search button, according to search results show the Icon on your screen

Comment: If  I do this, I need to create a map with all the Icons available, correct?
Something like:
{ 'arrow-down': Icons.arrow-donw,
'school': Icons.school,
...
 };

Comment: Yeah, exactly! Did you try?

Comment: It works, but it'll be a lot of work to make this Map.
Here is the code: https://github.com/UnDer-7/cade-onibus-mobile/blob/master/lib/widgets/icon_picker.dart
The key methods are _handleSearch to make the filtering, and _iconsMap to create the Map
When I'm done, I'll make a package with this widget

Comment: The layout is broken, but the search is working

Comment: take an IconData var above the class, update it according to search and then setState()

Comment: Have a look here https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_iconpicker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just published the exact package you need here:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_iconpicker

have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

So this one does not have a search, but may help others looking for a icon picker in Flutter. This was something I was dreading making myself but ended up being relatively easy.

**IconPicker Widget:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IconPicker extends StatelessWidget {
  static List<IconData> icons = [
    Icons.ac_unit,
    Icons.access_alarm,
    Icons.access_time,
    // all the icons you want to include
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      spacing: 5,
      children: <Widget>[
        for (var icon in icons)
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context, icon),
            child: Icon(icon),
          )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Example usage in a dialog:**

```dart
Future<void> _showIconPickerDialog() async {
    IconData iconPicked = await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            'Pick an icon',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          content: IconPicker(),
        );
      },
    );

    if (iconPicked != null) {
      debugPrint('Icon changed to $iconPicked');
      setState(() {
        myObject.icon = iconPicked;
      });
    }
  }
```

Here is a full list of all Flutter material icons in a list:
https://github.com/NedWilbur/FlutterIconList/blob/master/icons.dart